# windows 64bit problem

Tags: windows, win64

I have developed a windows application using C# VS 2008 and Sql 2005 express,
i have testes the application on my machine and it works fine,
my machine is win32 bit, when i tried the application on windows 64bit it keeps giving me an error message on the start of the application,although i installed the sql express on that machine
but should i install .NETframwork3.5sp1  64 bit also? , the target machine is widows 7 64bit,
also is there a technology or a way to make the application work in the following sequence:
1- the CD is auto run
2- the setup checks for the installed prerequists and install any necessery one without the interference of the user.
one last question,should i rebuild the application on an 64 bit machine to make it work on 64 bit machine?
thankx

Comment: It might help if you told us what the error message was...

Comment: Please ask one question at the time, you'll probably get better feedback then.

Answer (score 0):

In your build Settings, change from "Any CPU" to "Win32". You most propably use some native API calls which will load native DLL's. YOu can't load a 32bit DLL into a x64 process, so that will fail, if .NET scales your application up to 64 bit. Compiling with the Win32 setting will prevent .NET on the target mashine to scale your application up.

Comment: does this mean it will work on both platforms without any problems?

Comment: @renad, yes, but "only" as 32-bit process, which is limited to about 2GB of usable memory for the process even if the machine has more.

Comment: why it takes too long for the project to be build after i did what u said Lucero?